# Cognos prompt functprompt function

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I'm using to paramters with following commands:

`[BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[STAGES] in (prompt('STAGES1','string','Arrival announced'))`

and

`[BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[NEXTSTAGE] in (prompt('NEXTSTAGE','string','Arrival announced'))`

As you see what i'm trying to do is set default value in case user didn't select one both of them are optional.

When running the report i get this error:

`"XQE-DAT-0001`

```
    Data source adapter error: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=PROMPT;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.63.123 - when processing query: SELECT
```

"COGNOS"."TERMINALNAME" AS "TERMINALNAME",
"COGNOS"."CCN" AS "CCN",
"COGNOS"."CIDENTIFICATION" AS "CIDENTIFICATION",
"COGNOS"."STAGES" AS "STAGES",
"COGNOS"."NEXTSTAGE" AS "NEXTSTAGE",
SUM("COGNOS"."TIMETAKEN") AS "TIMETAKEN"
FROM
"KAP"."COGNOS" "COGNOS"
WHERE
"COGNOS"."STAGES" IN (
prompt('STAGES1','string','Arrival announced') ) AND
"COGNOS"."NEXTSTAGE" IN (
prompt('NEXTSTAGE','string','Arrival announced') )
GROUP BY
"COGNOS"."TERMINALNAME",
"COGNOS"."CCN",
"COGNOS"."CIDENTIFICATION",
"COGNOS"."STAGES",
"COGNOS"."NEXTSTAGE"."

I keep trying all day to get to set default value to parameter in case user didn't select but didn't find a way to get it run successfully. Anyone had luck with that ?

Answer (score 2):

```
[BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[STAGES] in (#promptmany('STAGES1','string','''Arrival announced''')#)
```

and

```
[BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[NEXTSTAGE] in (#promptmany('NEXTSTAGE','string','''Arrival announced''')#)
```